# Does calling a short method effect efficiency?

Tags: java, performance, function

I've created a few posts around here. I want to get into good programming habits. I've created a BMR calculator, and the following class packs all the user data and methods which use the data together:

```
public class User {

    private int age;
    private String gender; // todo: use an Enum
    private double height; // height stored in cm, weight in kg (so if user enters in feet/lbs, conversions are done to cm/kg and *THEN* passed through to constructor below)
    private double weight;
    private double activityMultiplier; // todo: use an Enum  (possibly)
    private int bmr;
    private int tdee;

    // This constructor is called everytime the program is run, used to create a User object to pack all user information together. This information comes from the UI which is coded in BMRMain
    public User(int age, String gender, double height, double weight,
        double activityMultiplier) {
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.activityMultiplier = activityMultiplier;

        bmr = calcBMR();
        tdee = calcTDEE(bmr); // Calculates and stores tdee regardless of user selecting the option, but does not display if user did not select the option
    }

    /**
     * If user input is correct, this method will calculate the BMR value of the user given their input and measurement choices.
     * 
     * @param None
     * @return BMR Value
     */
    public final int calcBMR() {
        int offset = gender.equals("M") ? 5 : -161;
        // This is the body of the calculations - different offset used depending on gender. Conversions to kg and cm done earlier so no conversions needed here.
        // The formula for male and female is similar - only the offset is different.
        return (int) (Math.round((10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) + offset)); // This is the Miffin St-Jeor formula, calculations done in cm/kg
        }

    /**
     * If the user selects the TDEE option, this method will be executed after the calcBMR() method. 
     * A value from the calcBMR() method will be passed down to this method, and is multiplied
     * by the activity level parameter passed into this method.
     * 
     * @param bmr (output from calcBMR() method
     * @return TDEE Value
     */
    public final int calcTDEE(int bmr) {
        return (int) Math.round(bmr * activityMultiplier);
    }


    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public double getActivityMultiplier() {
        return activityMultiplier;
    }

    public int getBMR() {
        return bmr;
    }

    public int getTDEE() {
        return tdee;
    }

}
```

Note in the constructor that `calcTDEE()` is always called (also note the comment). My UI gives the user an option on whether on not they want to calculate TDEE, but even if they select No, it calculates it and stores it in a variable anyway (but does not output the value to the user).

`CalcTDEE()` is a short method, however is it inefficient to calculate this value even if the user does not want to see it? Am I losing out on anything? If so, what's a better way to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: Computers can perform millions of calculations a second. This is **highly** unlikely to be the cause of any performance issues. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) -- DonaldKnuth

Comment: @ElliottFrisch My Functional Programming lecturer used to always tell us that every lecture. Guess it didn't stick into my head well enough huh. Thanks :)

Comment: Although, how does one know what falls in the critical 3% part? :p

Comment: Measurement (benchmarks). But, in a GUI application, displaying the window performs many more calculations than performing a single calculation. I think I'd prefer a `private` function for your use case.

Comment: So you'd recommend I make `calcBMR()` and `calcTDEE()` private? What are the reasons?

Comment: You should not call overridable methods from the constructor. This is because a subclass may not have been fully initialized at the time an overriding method in that subclass is called. Making the methods `private` makes them safe to call from the constructor, since private methods are not overridden (although they may be _hidden_). Another reason to make the methods `private` is if there is no reason for the methods to be called from outside the class.

Comment: @TedHopp thanks for the reply. I believe I did not call any overridable methods from the constructor (I could be wrong here). Does declaring methods as final not make them non-overridable, regardless of them being private or public? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, declaring them `final` avoids the overriding problem. (Like KDM, I missed that initially.) if you see the possibility that client code would want to call either of those methods, then leave them as `public`. From the code you posted, however, it seems that you'd rather have client code call `getBMR()` and `getTDEE()` rather than repeating the calculations of the `calc*()` methods.

Comment: @TedHopp Ah okay. Yes I agree with what you said, therefore I also think it's a good idea to make the `calcBMR()` and `calcTDEE()` methods private and use `getBMR()` and `getTDEE()` since the value will be calculated as soon as a User object is created. From what I can see, there's no way my code can create a User object but not have values for `bmr` and `tdee` - if the `User` class is instantiated then a `bmr` and `tdee` value will 100% be calculated. (Do you agree?)

Saves calculation time also (however miniscule the difference is).

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, it might not matter. But if performance of `calcBMR` is an issue do a lazy calculation for the `bmr` value. Initialise `bmr` to a invalid value and in `getBMR` if `bmr` is invalid calculate `bmr`. Return bmr.

Couple of other improvements, I can suggest:

1. Do not call methods that can be overrideable in constructor. Either make them private or final.
2. You are using some magic numbers: 5, -161 etc. Define `static final` variables in the class for these. That should make your code more understandable.

Comment: 1. The methods that are called in the constructor are `public final` - I thought this was enough to make them non-overridable?
2. Do I define these as global variables, or within the calcBMR() method itself?

Comment: @F.Tahir (1) sorry I missed that. Constants are usually defined at the class level and given ALLCAPS names. If you need to use them from other classes, you can use `public` instead of `private`.

Comment: Okay. http://pastebin.com/vyajaeUz

I've edited it, is this what you were meaning? Does this really add much value to a user whose not familiar with the equation though? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the stream of questions. Your first suggestion about lazy calculation has me thinking - not something I think I'll implement as of yet, but out of curiosity in my `getBMR()` method, how would I check if `bmr` is an appropriate value? Is a negative value for `bmr` invalid enough, and then just do something like `if (bmr >= 0) {
   return bmr;
  } else {
   bmr = calcBMR();
  }
  return bmr;`
after initialising bmr to say, -10?

Comment: Having constants instead of magic numbers add value? Sure. Even when you look at this code down the line, the code will be much more readable. As for the formula, I expect that to be given in the comment to the method,so that a new user (or yourself at a later time) do not need to hunt for that. As for the lazy calculation you can use any invalid value - again define a constant INVALID_BMR to hold that value. In those cases where the whole range of values or valid for a calculated field, you can use a boolean variable `bmrCalculated` to tell you whether the value is calculated or not.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Yup, I've added a few extra comments regarding the equation and how the offset works. Provides useful indeed. Thanks for that.

As for lazy calculations, how exactly does this speed things up as the method will need to be called at least once anyway? Am I missing the point somewhere? Does the way I suggested how to implement this "lazy calculation" not make sense?

Going to bed now so not able to reply for a while. Appreciate the feedback. Thanks once again.